# WinAPI CryptBinaryToString without a null-terminator

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using a string as both the buffer and the output for WinAPI's `CryptBinaryToString`. When the function writes to the buffer, it writes an extra null terminator for the allocation (and needs it as such).

```
DWORD size;
CryptBinaryToString(..., &size, ...);

std::string buf;
buf.resize(size);
CryptBinaryToString(..., &buf[0], &size, ...);

return buf.erase(buf.size()-1);
```

How can I call it so that it does not try to add a null terminator? It seems unnecessary since we're provided a size.

[None of the flags seem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa) to indicate its possible, but there are flags that aren't documented, so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: What's the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Storing into a `std::string`. I dont want to call `.erase(dwSize)` because I'm working with many strings and the overhead is substantial.

Comment: Do you wish to prevent `CryptBinaryToString()` from appending a `\0` to the end of `pszString`? Because the documentation says it always appends it. But you can figure out where the end is from `pcchString` and do whatever you need with it.

Comment: @chakaz Correct

Comment: You don't have to `erase` anything. [std::basic_string::data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) is well prepared to receive a null-terminated string, without actually containing the NUL terminator as part of the controlled sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand what is the issue. Is there an issue storing the result inside a `std::string`? If so you could use the constructor that takes a pointer and a size, and use `pcchString - 1`

Comment: @IInspectable I write the data into a `.resize`'d string. I do not construct a string from a raw `char*` because that would require copying.

Comment: So then, `resize()` it to `n` characters, call `data()` and get a buffer of size `n + 1`. You can then write a zero-terminated string into the buffer. So long as you only ever overwrite the character at location `data() + size()` with `CharT()`, the behavior is well defined. No overallocation required, no truncation. You need to understand C++ standardese, though.

Comment: @IInspectable Post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: That's not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: I'll edit the question

Comment: @IInspectable Please post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to ask `CryptBinaryToString()` to omit outputting a null terminator.

However, resizing a `std::string` to remove trailing characters (whether you use `resize()`, `erase()`, `pop_back()`, etc) will not reallocate the `std::string`'s data, it will merely decrement the value of its `size()` so that subsequent operations on the `std::string` will ignore those characters in memory.

A better option is to simply omit the null terminator when sizing the `std::string` initially.  In C++11 and later, at least, `std::string` is required to allocate space for a null-terminator, even though it is not included in the `size()`, and writing to the `char` at index `size()` is well-defined as long as the new value is `char(0)` only.

```
DWORD size;
if (!CryptBinaryToString(..., &size, ...)) // <-- size will include the null terminator
{
    // error handling...
}

std::string buf;

if (size > 1) // <-- is not an "empty" (null terminator only) string?
{
    buf.resize(size-1); // <-- ignore the null terminator, though it will still be present in memory

    if (!CryptBinaryToString(..., &buf[0], &size, ...))
    {
        // error handling...
    }
}

return buf;
```